# Which config files does gsutil actually require

Tags: docker, circleci, gsutil

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I am trying to CRUD data on a google cloud bucket via gsutil from my staging environment which runs via Circle CI. I am running the gsutil command from a docker container, here is the docker-compose:

```
services:
  bucketstuff
    image: bucketstuff:latest
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ~/.config:/root/.config
      - ~/.kube:/root/.kube
```

This works on my local machine but not on my staging environment (Circle CI agent). So I am trying to track down what config files I actually need to use gsutil.

Also, gsutil runs fine directly on the Circle CI agent. From this I deduce gsutil is configured correctly on the Circle CI agent, but the correct config files are not getting mapped through to my docker container.

Error message on staging environment:

> You are attempting to access protected data with no configured
>   credentials. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/console#/project
>   and sign up for an account, and then run the "gcloud auth login"

Answer (score 0):

To see which config files are being loaded in your working environment, run `gsutil version -l`:

```
$ gsutil version -l
[...]
config path(s): /Users/bob/.boto
[...]
```

If you're unable to load your Boto config file(s) to one of the default locations (e.g. /etc/boto.cfg or ~/.boto), you can tell gsutil where to find the boto file via setting the `BOTO_CONFIG` environment variable.